# Application for extracting XML tags from a document

Tags: xml, extract

I am looking for an application that will extract all XML tags contained within a specific XML file. For example I would get a list: `<XML_TAG_ONE>,<XML_TAG_TWO>` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>[xml2](http://ofb.net/%7Eegnor/xml2/examples)</strike> [xml2](https://github.com/clone/xml2)

```
  <foo.xml xml2 | cut -d= -f1 | sort -u
```

or

```
  <foo.xml xml2 | cut -d= -f1 | sort -u | 2xml
```

etc

omit the `sort -u` if you are interested in repetitions & duplicates.

If you don't want to see attributes

```
  <foo.xml xml2 | grep -v @ | cut -d= -f1 | sort -u | 2xml
```

If you want to use xml2 on Windows you'll probably need Cygwin or unxutils or gnuwin32 etc.